# How to compile PHP from source on MAC / OSX

Tags: php, c, macos, compilation

Just for learning purposes, i tried to compile the current php source code from [github](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/INSTALL), following the install instructions (see link).
I know that there are many other ways to achieve to install php like with homebrew and so on, but i am really interested in the way to compile it by myself just for education.

At first, i stumbled upon the fact, that there is no ./configure, even if the install document tells to execute this script.

So i googled around and found the following command to produce a ./configure - script:

```
$ autoreconf -i
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
glibtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
glibtoolize: Consider adding 'AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])' to configure.in,
glibtoolize: and rerunning glibtoolize and aclocal.
glibtoolize: Consider adding '-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
```

No the file exists, but the execution of that script failed with a missing install-sh/install.sh/shtool:

```
$ ./configure 
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/local/bin/ggrep
checking for egrep... /usr/local/bin/ggrep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/local/bin/sed
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."
```

So i installed shtool via homebrew, but the same error still occurs.

Who can help me?

Comment: Which version do you want to install? If you want to compile the php7 alpha 1 you can download a release package which has a configure and install-sh script inside.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the source from php.net, e.g.

```
http://php.net/downloads.php
```

It comes with a working configure